# How to decode this string (it's hex?)?

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying to understand how encoding/decoding string works in Python, but I'm getting pretty confused.

If I've got a string like this:

```
'\x87\x0e)\xb9\xb0\x0f\t"c\xc7\xf1\x97B\xc6\x17\xee\xab\x1d\xbf\xc0\xd0\x06j\xc3'
```

Which type is this? Hex? And how to convert it to utf-8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way you can construct Unicode object out of this string

```
u='\x87\x0e)\xb9\xb0\x0f\t"c\xc7\xf1\x97B\xc6\x17\xee\xab\x1d\xbf\xc0\xd0\x06j\xc3'.decode('UTF16')
print type(u)
```

Comment: print u.encode('utf-8') should return "ງ뤩ྰ∉읣韱왂ᶫ삿ې썪" ? How do you now this is UTF16? Is there a function who tells me wich encoding is?

Comment: I just tried to guess an encoding that will work. Answers the question about what original string could be. For example, utf8 won't work if you try.